# SignalR, KO: Show loading message when server function invoke

Tags: knockout.js, signalr

I've an application in which on button click I called a server function through SignalR.
I changed a status after function done, but how to show loading message between function init and done?

```
self.readyBill = function (data, event) {
    self.hub.server.billReady(self.OrderId).done(function () {
        self.Status("B");
        window.location.href = "BillDetail.aspx?Code=" + self.OrderId;
    }).fail(function (err) {
        self.error(err);
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.loading = ko.observable(false);

self.readyBill = function (data, event) {
    self.loading(true);

    self.hub.server.billReady(self.OrderId).done(function () {
        self.Status("B");
        window.location.href = "BillDetail.aspx?Code=" + self.OrderId;
    }).fail(function (err) {
        self.error(err);
        return false;
    }).always(function() {
        self.loading(false);
    });
}
```

No you can bind `loading` in your view:

```
<div data-bind="visible: loading">Loading, please wait</div>
```

Comment: Hey @janfoeh, can you describe what this `always()` do?

Comment: `.always` is always executed, no matter if the request succeeded or failed.

Comment: Thanks @janfoeh for all effort. Can you provide documentation link where I can find description of these functions?